# adding checkbox not getting displayed in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add a checkbox but it is not getting displayed.

```
var svg = d3.select("#mainchart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

svg.append('input').attr('type','checkbox').attr("x","400").attr("y","-215");
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) doesn't have a checkbox element. To add a checkbox to the page, it needs to appended to a vanilla html element (in this case, the body of the page):

```
d3.select("body").append('input').attr('type','checkbox')
```

Edit: to control where the checkbox appears, select another element instead of body:

```
d3.select("#checkBoxDiv").append('input').attr('type','checkbox')
```

would change this:

```
<div id="checkBoxDiv></div>
```

into this:

```
<div id="checkBoxDiv>
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

You could also hard code the last line in your html file and still select the checkbox later with:

```
d3.select("#about").select('input')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have html tags inside the svg namespace without using foreignObject. [Here is a simple example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/3085882), as answered on your question cross-posted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/QTbiaSRc16w).